# HTML Sidebar Closed By Default

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently developing a website to test my django skills, and my HTML skills are not up to par. This might be a really simple question, but how do I get my sidebar to close by default? I've tried to look at other questions but they don't solve my question in my scenario. As a side note, I got the sidebar off of [here](https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar).

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                <strong>BS</strong>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                            About
                    </a>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                        Pages
                    </a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <main role="main" class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"> 
                        {% if messages %}
                            {% for message in messages %}
                                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                                    {{ message }}
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <div ml-3 mr-3>  
                            {% block content %}
                            {% endblock %}    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
    #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a span {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#sidebarCollapse').click(function(){
 $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -80px !important;
  }

  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }

  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }

  #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
  #sidebar .CTAs {
    display: none;
  }

  #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
  }

  #sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }

  #sidebar ul li a span {
    font-size: 0.85em;
  }

  #sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
  }

  #sidebar ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }

  #sidebar ul li a i {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }

  #sidebar {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar  -->
  <nav id="sidebar" class="active">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
      <strong>BS</strong>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
          <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
          Home
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
          About
        </a>
        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
          <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
          Pages
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
  
  <!-- Page Content  -->
  <div id="content">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
          CLICK ME
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          
          <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
            message
          </div>
          
          <div ml-3 mr-3>
            content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can add the class 'active' to the #sidebar, and it be hidden on page load.

I noticed that you were missing this crucial JQuery snippet that toggles a class to trigger the show/hide:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Then I added this css rule... They have a margin-left of -250px, but using that seems too much, so I reduced it to -100px

```
#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```